# Is there any CMS written in .Net and can be used as a template?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

Is there any CMS written in asp.Net and open to be used as a template?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few CMS written in ASP.NET. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#ASP.NET).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/

Comment: I have used this, and can recommend it. It's highly productive, documentation is not the best though. Solid architecture and design. When experienced you can implement simple DNN modules providing real business value in 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new CMS by the guys from Channel9 called oxite...
http://oxite.codeplex.com/releases/view/20210

Comment: Oxite was slated by the community and will soon be discontinued as they are making a new CMS called Orchard, I would stay away from Oxite if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

When you say written as a template do you mean that the CMS has templating capabilities?

If that is what you mean I would recommend http://www.umbraco.org, it is very customisable and gives you total control over the HTML output, it was also recently used by the ASP.Net website.

I hope this helps.